# WebCache google and angular error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with **angularjs** and **googlecache**.
When access my page with google cache, into console i have next error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedCb @ angular.js:11552$get @ angular.js:12203e @ angular.js:5198(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5317d @ angular.js:4559e @ angular.js:4696(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5317d @ angular.js:4559e @ angular.js:4696(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5320m @ angular.js:305eb @ angular.js:5316d @ angular.js:1437yc @ angular.js:1735Zd @ angular.js:1374(anonymous function) @ angular.js:20798o.Callbacks.j @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2o.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2o.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2I @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2

Without **google cache**, my site works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google Cache works different than crawler 
https://www.seroundtable.com/fetch-as-google-renders-angularjs-as-cache-html-page-21413.html